# Arranging items in an inventory

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm working on an inventory system I made following a short tutorial that leaves you stranded. I've managed to get the items removed and rearrange to the correct order somewhat. For some reason though, if I click on the last item in my inventory, then on the first item, the items do not rearrange correctly.

```
public class Inventory {
    var itemsInInventory:Array;
    var inventorySprite:Sprite;
    var itemNum:int;

    public function Inventory(parentMC:MovieClip) {
        itemNum=0;
        itemsInInventory = new Array();
        inventorySprite = new Sprite();
        inventorySprite.x = 50;
        inventorySprite.y = 360;
        parentMC.addChild(inventorySprite);
    }

    public function makeInventoryItems(arrayOfItems:Array){
        for(var i:int = 0; i < arrayOfItems.length; i++){
            arrayOfItems[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, getItem);
            arrayOfItems[i].buttonMode = true;
        }

    }
    public function getItem(e:MouseEvent){
        var item:MovieClip = MovieClip(e.currentTarget);
        itemsInInventory.push(item);
        inventorySprite.addChild(item);
        item.x = (itemsInInventory.length-1)*40;
        item.y = 0;
        item.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, getItem);
        item.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, useItem);
    }   
    public function useItem(e:MouseEvent){
        var item:MovieClip = MovieClip(e.currentTarget);
        itemNum = item.x;
        inventorySprite.removeChild(item);
        itemsInInventory.splice(item, 1);
        sortInventory();
    }
    public function sortInventory(){
        for(var i:int = 0; i < itemsInInventory.length; i++){
            if(itemsInInventory[i].x > itemNum){
                itemsInInventory[i].x -= 40;
            }
        }
        itemNum=0;
    }
}
```

I belive thats all the coding info I need to provide for help solving this mystery. 
Also, a link to the game for testing. If you would like a link for a download of the game, please ask.
[LINK](http://www.fastswf.com/8vZl4ow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of substracting 40px, just set their position again:

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < itemsInInventory.length; i++){
    itemsInInventory[i].x = i*40;
}
```

Also, I did not even know that it is possible to give an object reference to the splice function, I would rather use:

```
itemsInInventory.splice(itemsInInventory.indexOf(item), 1);
```

And remove the event listener from the item when you delete it from the inventory in the `useItem` function.

```
item.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, useItem);
```

EDIT:
With Flash Player 10, Adobe introduced the `Vector` class which is kind of the same as the `Array` class, but it can only store one data type. In your case it would be `MovieClip` or `Sprite`. The `Vector` class is singificantly faster and more developer friendly because you can see the help from the IDE when you are typing `myVector[i].`. I recommend using that instead, although there is nothing wrong with `Array`. It is just outdated a bit, but is helpful when you want to store more data types.

```
myVector:Vector.<MovieClip> = new Vector.<MovieClip>();
```

Comment: here, have all of my love! Will let you know if this works

also, im pretty sure my splice wasnt workign at all, I jsut had no idea how to reference it the way you did.

It worked perfect :) The only reason it wasnt working in the first palce was because of the splice lol :) thanks alot man !

Comment: That splice was interesting. :) Welcome to the Stackoverflow community. Please, take the one minute tour to understand how the site works and I hope you stay! http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Oh wow, thanks alot for the Vector/array info! and i will be staying :) iv used this site for a while, iv just never found myself stumped enough to make an account lolol :D